# Why I can't find the "printf" in the file of /usr/lib/libSystem.dylib with macOS Catalina?

Tags: c, macos, assembly

I wrote a c program by calling the function "printf" and "sqrt". I use gcc(Apple clang version 12.0.0) to compile it without any linked library, and it works. So I want to see which lib is dependent on it. I exec `otool -L a.out`, and the result is that: `/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1281.100.1)`. So I want to see if those two functions, printf and sqrt, are defined in this lib, then I exec `nm /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib | grep printf`. However, there is nothing output as well as sqrt. I just want to know why the symbols of printf and sqrt are not in the libSystem.B.dylib, or there is something strange happening when gcc link the lib in macOS?

Comment: Note that there is no file `/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib`.

Comment: Not sure about MacOS, but on my system you have to use `nm -D` to see dynamic symbols.  Otherwise you only see "normal" symbols and a dynamic library typically doesn't have any.

Comment: @NateEldredge macOS `nm` doesn't have a `-D` option it seems.  Also, this file doesn't exist.

Comment: @nobody Ah yes, I only checked on Big Sur.  Now on to find the shared cache...

Comment: Please show us how you linked your program. Commonly some standard libraries are automatically linked, and `printf()` and `sqrt()` might be added statically.